# Apollo Client (React): Possible to get normalized data from Query object?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

The `Query.data` object of `react-apollo` provides data in a nested form, like so:

```
{
    "findUser": [
      {
        "__typename": "User",
        "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba013",
        "email": "Lloyd.Nikolaus@yahoo.com",
        "posts": [
          {
            "__typename": "BlogPost",
            "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba016",
            "title": "Dolorem voluptatem molestiae",
            "comments": [
              {
                "__typename": "Comment",
                "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba019",
                "message":
                  "Alias quod est voluptatibus aut quis sunt aut numquam."
              },
              {
                "__typename": "Comment",
                "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01b",
                "message": "Harum quia asperiores nemo."
              },
              {
                "__typename": "Comment",
                "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01c",
                "message": "Vel veniam consectetur laborum."
              },
              {
                "__typename": "Comment",
                "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01e",
                "message":
                  "Possimus beatae vero recusandae beatae quas ut commodi laboriosam."
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I have a use case where I need the data in normalized form, like so:

```
{
  "comments": {
    "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba019": {
      "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba019",
      "message": "Alias quod est voluptatibus aut quis sunt aut numquam."
    },
    "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01b": {
      "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01b",
      "message": "Harum quia asperiores nemo."
    },
    "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01c": {
      "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01c",
      "message": "Vel veniam consectetur laborum."
    },
    "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01e": {
      "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01e",
      "message":
        "Possimus beatae vero recusandae beatae quas ut commodi laboriosam."
    }
  },
  "blogPosts": {
    "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba016": {
      "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba016",
      "title": "Dolorem voluptatem molestiae",
      "comments": [
        "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba019",
        "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01b",
        "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01c",
        "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba01e"
      ]
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba013": {
      "id": "5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba013",
      "email": "Lloyd.Nikolaus@yahoo.com",
      "posts": ["5a6efb94b0e8c36f99fba016"]
    }
  }
}
```

Seeing as Apollo allready does cache persistance of data in normalized form, is there a way to access the relevant response data in normalized form, without the use of a separate normalizing process like with the [graphql-normalizr](https://github.com/monojack/graphql-normalizr) library?

If possible I'd like to avoid the overhead of double normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to read the flattened data in the cache with `client.readFragment()`

Have a look at the documentation here:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#readfragment